# Reopen review audit -- were the questions closed to begin with?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, vote-to-reopen

Consider https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2857976

If you suppose that the question was closed in the first place, the edit (https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18304689/4) did not change the nature of the question enough to merit a reopen vote.  I also don't see any evidence that the question was closed in the first place.

(to clarify my thought process: As I understand it, the point of a reopen review is to evaluate whether a question should be reopened.  That implicitly assumes that the question was closed in the first place.)

Is this question an anomaly, or is it wrong to assume that questions in reopen reviews were closed in the first place?

Comment: That seems like a perfectly valid question, why did you respond "leave closed" in the first place?

Comment: @Kevin I presumed that at least five other people deemed it close-worthy (given that it was in the review queue), and the revision didn't really change the open-worthiness of the question

Answer (score 3):

It's a review audit.  It's designed to make sure that you're paying attention.  It will pick a question that hasn't been closed, and based on some metrics is considered a "good question" that *shouldn't* be closed.  Then if you vote to close it, we have evidence that you aren't paying attention when reviewing.  If you state that it should be reopened, then it helps to show that you're paying attention to the items before acting on them.

Comment: So you are saying that it's wrong to presuppose that questions in the *reopen review queue* were closed to begin with?

Comment: @Nirk It's perfectly acceptable to treat each question as if it's closed.  They won't all actually be closed, as some will be audits, but you don't really need to worry about that, just respond to each post based on what you would do if it were closed, as the review states.

Comment: So let me phrase the question differently.  Suppose a question was erroneously closed BUT the edit doesn't make any substantial change.  If you suppose that people voted to close it already, what is the correct response?  As it is phrased, the review is asking "does the edit change the question in a way that merits a reopen?".

Comment: @Nirk If you think that the question should be reopened, then vote to reopen it.  If you think that the question should remain closed, then vote to keep it closed.  If you are unsure, skip.

Comment: @Nirk Oh, and for the record, the question that the queue is asking is, "Should this question be reopened?".  That's all.  It has nothing to do (directly) with the edit.  The edit can be terrible, but if the question should be reopened, then that's what you should vote for.

Comment: Servy it actually pointed out that the question was revised, which seems to suggest that the focus should be on the revision

Comment: @Nirk The question may have been revised, or it may not be.  That's one of several possible ways that the item could have been added to the queue.  Regardless, no, you should not be focusing on the revision.  You should be focusing on whether or not the question should be reopened.  If it should be, you should vote to reopen it.  I see nothing at all in the review queue UI to indicate otherwise.

Comment: the exact message was "This question was edited after it was closed. Should it be reopened?" and the verbiage makes no sense if it was not closed in the first place.  I understand the need for audits, but the right type of audit would be a question that was deemed open-worthy (for example, a question that was closed but reopened after the OP gave enough details to make the question worthy).

Comment: @Nirk I looked at the queue myself and quoted the exact question at the top of the review queue.  It merely asks if the question should be reopened.  As to your proposal, if a question was written such that 5 people felt it should be closed, clearly it's not a clear enough case that it should be an audit.  If you take a highly rated question that nobody has ever felt the need to close the odds are much higher it will be clear to any reader that it should be opened, not closed.  I'm simply not seeing what's confusing here.  You have three options (buttons) all of which make complete sense.